# The Hodge number $h^{2,0}$ of (finite) quotient variety of a K3 surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be an (algebraic) K3 surface, then we have $H^{2,0}(X)=\langle \omega_X\rangle$, where $\omega_X$ is the period. Suppose $G=\langle g\rangle$ is a finite group acting on $X$ and $g$ as an automorphism of $X$ doesn't fix $\omega_X$(e.g. $g$ is purely non-symplectic), then why is $h^{2,0}(X/G)=0$?

What's in my head is
$$
H^k(X,\mathbb{Q})^G\cong H^k(X/G,\mathbb{Q}). 
$$ by the Leray-Cartan-Serre spectral sequence. But it requires free action and it's of coefficient $\mathbb Q$. Do we have
$$
H^{i,j}(X)^G\cong H^{i,j}(X/G) 
$$ in general?

Also, I am not sure if we always have Hodge structure on normal varieties in general. Here $X/G$ is a normal variety, I guess we can define $H^{i,j}(X/G):=H^j(X/G,\omega_{X/G}^i)$? I know the canonical divisor is well-defined for normal varieties, so for my case that $X$ is K3, $H^{2,0}(X/G)$ is well defined but is $H^j(X/G,\omega_{X/G}^i)$ well-defined in general?

Comment: For your first question, note that $\pi^*\colon H^0(X/G, \omega)\to H^0(X, \omega)$ is injective (the quotient map $\pi$ is generically etale) and has image inside the invariants $H^0(X, \omega)^G$. In your situation, the latter group is trivial; we didn't need freeness of the action.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Thanks for the explanation! For $\pi^*$ to be injective, don't we require $X/G$ to be smooth? Also why the image is inside the $H^0(X,\omega)^G$, could you explain a little for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variety $X/G$ is an orbifold; on
a singular variety, the Hodge decomposition
does not work, but on an orbifold, it works
just as well. Then $G$ acts on $H^*(X,{\Bbb Q})$, and
$H^*(X/G,{\Bbb Q})$ is the space of $G$-invariants
(this is more or less a definition of
$H^*(X/G)$ for an orbifold).
Similarly, $H^{p,q}(X/G)$ is the space
of $G$-invariants in $H^{p,q}(X)$.
Then $H^{2,0}(X/G)= H^{2,0}(X)^G=0$ because your $G$-action
is not holomorphically symplectic.

To use this argument, you would probably
need to compare the orbifold cohomology
with the usual cohomology of $X/G$.
This is not very hard to do, see
https://www.pnas.org/content/42/6/359
I. Satake,
"ON A GENERALIZATION OF THE NOTION OF MANIFOLD",
PNAS June 1, 1956 42 (6) 359-363.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So is the sheaf of q-forms $\Omega^q$ well-defined for general varieties or we need the variety to be normal? Then how do we define the $\Omega^q$ on normal varieties? Do we just use the push-forward from a resolution map?

Comment: "Then how do we define the $Ω^q$ on normal varieties?"  As a pushforward or reflexization of the sheaf on holomorphic forms (sometimes), and sometimes, as the exterior power of the sheaf of Kahler differentials. There is no canonical way to do this, even for canonical/dualizing sheaf/bundle

Answer (score 0):

Going off Misha's comment above, here are three useful notions of differentials for a normal variety $X$:

1. The exterior powers $\Omega_X^p$ of the sheaf of K"ahler differentials.
2. The reflexive differentials $\Omega_X^{[p]}: = (\Omega_X^p)^{**} \cong j_*\Omega_{X_{\mathrm{reg}}}^p$, where $j:X_{\mathrm{reg}} \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion of the regular locus.  The isomorphism requires normality.
3. $\pi_*\Omega_{\tilde X}^p$, where $\pi:\tilde X \to X$ is a resolution of singularities.

The sheaves $\Omega_X^p$ often have torsion, so we look at the other options (especially when studying Hodge theory).  For each $p$, there is an inclusion $\pi_*\Omega_{\tilde X}^p \hookrightarrow j_*\Omega_{X_{\mathrm{reg}}}^p$.  To see that these are in general different, the classic example is to let $X$ be the affine cone of an elliptic curve.  Then the singular point is Cohen-Macaulay but not rational, and so by Kempf's criterion the inclusion $\pi_*\omega_{\tilde X} \hookrightarrow j_*\omega_{X_{\mathrm{reg}}}$ is strict.  What's less classical, and maybe unintuitive, is that $\pi_*\Omega_{\tilde X}^1 \cong j_*\Omega_{X_{\mathrm{reg}}}^1$ in this case.

In your case of quotient singularities, these notions agree for all $p$.